# Restart a gif animation without reloading the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animated-gif

Is it possible to restart a gif animation without downloading the file every time?
My current code looks like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'imgages/src/myImage.gif';

$('#id').css('background-image', 'url("' + img.src + '?x=' + Date.now() + '")' );
```

**Edit**

When I insert the gif into the dom it didn't restart the gif animation. I can only achieve this by appending a random string to the image src but this will download the image again.

I want to know if it is possible to restart the gif animation without downloading the gif.

Comment: what do you mean by `resetting gif animation`?

Comment: A GIF *usually* loops infinitely (or you can make it that way via photo editing software, e.g. Photoshop), what do you mean `restart a gif animation` ?

Comment: Why don't you amend the GIF file in an editor to make it loop? Much easier than messing with the element in JS every x seconds

Comment: @Scorpion looping is an option which can be enabled/disabled on GIF files when saving them. It sounds like OPs GIF has this disabled.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991904/why-the-gif-animation-only-play-one-time-in-jquery

Comment: @Scorpion : the OP never said he wants to loop the gif animation. I have the same requirement where 1) I made a gif that does NOT loop, on purpose 2) I want to start the animation when the user clicks on a button. The animation should then play only once and does not loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had similar requirement.

```
var img = document.createElement("img"),
    imageUrl = "http://i73.photobucket.com/albums/i231/charma13/love240.gif";
img.src = imageUrl;
document.body.appendChild(img);

window.restartAnim = function () {
    img.src = "";
    img.src = imageUrl;
}
```

Comment: My above answer will not reload the Image again. So I guess it suits your requirements.

Comment: Now 2021 - I used the above and it  works fine on normal screens, but doesnt seem to on a mobile. On a mobile - if I wait a couple of minute it DOES restart the animation, but not if refresh immediately.    Can someone confirm/negate this behaviour please.   Is there technology on mobiles that effect this?

Answer (score 7):

for example on facebook - animated emoticons are not .gifs but a set of static frames on png file with dynamically set background offset. This way you have full control over your animation from javascript - you can even pause/unpause it or change its speed.

It's possible to split your .gif file into separate frames and generate a .png file on server side dynamically.

This looks like a good weekend project for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
restartGif(imgElement){ 
  let element = document.getElementById(imgElement);
  if (element) {
     var imgSrc = element.src;
     element.src = imgSrc; 
  }
}

// Example:

restartGif("gif_box")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by adjusting the image's `display` attribute before restarting the gif. Also, set the timeout to make sure that the restarting the gif will run after the image attribute is changed.

```js
const img = document.getElementById("gif");
img.style = "display: none;";
img.style = "display: block;";
setTimeout(() => {
  img.src = img.src;
}, 0);
```

This is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21104927/14910436).

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshgif() {
  var giffile = $(".gif-class");
  giffile.src = giffile.src;
}
```

Comment: Please a bit of explanation to your answer

Answer (score -1):

Just make it loop forever? otherwise you could use an ajax request every (duration of gif) to restart it.

even with javascript it would be possible;

```
var gif
window.onload=function () {
  gif=document.getElementById('id')
  setInterval(function () {
    gif.src=gif.src.replace(/\?.*/,function () {
      return '?'+new Date()
    })
  },5000)//duration of your gif
}
```

Comment: AJAX request? For what? There isn't even AJAX in your example code ^^

Comment: Thats why i said 'even with javascript it would be possible', ajax could just reload the div. But is would be a bit odd to use Jquery only for a div refresh.

Comment: No, I meant: Why use AJAX to "refresh" a gif? The gif is already there, no need to fetch data again from a server. Besides, AJAX is javascript, so your sentence does not make much sense.

Comment: Hmm yep, that makes more sense. Didn't know ajax always would fetch form db again.

Comment: @joostmakaay this was actually the easiest answer to implement btw (4 years later), and it's not TOO hacky, ignore the haters :)

Comment: OP wanted to restart the GIF at will, not when it would naturally loop.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you,

```
var img = new Image();
src = 'imgages/src/myImage.gif';
img.src=src;
$('body').append(img);
setInterval(function(){
    t=new Date().getTime();
    $("img").attr("src", src+'?'+t);
},5000);
```

Comment: wouldn't it reload the file again?

Answer (score -1):

create a function in javascript and then reput the image in the same place. when you want to replay the Gif call this function.

```
function replayGif(){
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = 'imgages/src/myImage.gif';

   $('#id').css('background-image', 'url("' + img.src + '?x=' + Date.now() + '")' );
}
```

Comment: This will reload the image from the server. I want a method to prevent this behaviour

Answer (score -1):

The simplest javascript solution:

Function:

```
function restartGif(ImageSelector){
  var imgSrc=document.querySelector(ImageSelector).src;
  document.querySelector(ImageSelector).src=imgSrc;
}
```

Call function:

```
restartGif(SELECTOR) // Example: restartGif('.homer')
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nv3dkscr/

Answer (score -2):

Try to set the src of the gif animation to itself or set it to an empty string followed by the original src again. ;)