# How to load a gif animated infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, infinite-loop, animated-gif

I have an animated gif in a website, but this animation is displayed only once.

How do I make that play infinitely?
http://tarketts.emblema78.com/

Regards!

Comment: make the gif infinite as it is programmed to run only once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart a gif animation without reloading the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831319/restart-a-gif-animation-without-reloading-the-file)

Comment: Another possible duplicate  [How do I make an existing animated GIF loop repeatedly?](http://superuser.com/questions/159212/how-do-i-make-an-existing-animated-gif-loop-repeatedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you want the GIF to loop, (repeat over and over again) This does not need code persay, the GIF just needed to be edited.

Here's the looped version of your GIF.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dove Man

Comment: No problem! Btw, I don't know if you noticed but on your website when you  select English as the language, the navigation tap says, "How We Are" Not, "Who We Are" I just thought you would want to know.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, we are testing and correcting, so thanks for the comment. It´s perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try putting it into video mode: i.e.

```
<img class=gif data-mode="video"
```

Comment: can you provide any references to browser support for that attribute?

Comment: well, without seeing the code, ( I just trie to give you and option) it's difficult to know what you need but this : http://rubentd.com/gifplayer/ seems like a food place to start. Maybe a simple work around.

Comment: okay so you are suggesting that the OP utilize [that jQuery plugin](http://rubentd.com/gifplayer/) which would require the user to utilize [jQuery](https://jquery.org/). Unless the OP added the `jQuery` tag or mentioned it in the description, you should make it clear that he/she would need to use that library and plugin