# How can you instantiate a .gif file in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app that does 3 things; displays the  elements in an array, adds an  element on button press and removes an  element on button press.

Inside of my image, I am displaying my local .gif file. My .gif file is a single animation .gif, I turned off infinite looping because I want the .gif to spawn in and then remain static.

My error comes when I add a second .gif  element to my array. Only the first element displays its animation and the rest display the final slide in the .gif.

I believe that I may be able to solve my issue if I manage to instantiate the  element but I am not sure how I would go about doing that.

Here is an excerpt from my code::

```
function App(){
    const [numbValue, numbUpdate] = useState(0);
    const [starsValue, starsUpdate] = useState(null);
    
    function DisplayGIF(numbToDisp){
      let value=[];
      for(let i=0;i<numbToDisp;i++){
        value.push(<img className="icon" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/once-star-filled.gif"} alt="animated star"/>)
      }
      starsUpdate(<>{value.map(element=>{return element;})}</>);
    }

    function Add(){
      numbUpdate(numbValue+1);
      DisplayGIF(numbValue+1);
    }

    function Sub(){
      numbUpdate(numbValue-1);
      DisplayGIF(numbValue-1);
    }

    return(<>
      <p onClick={Add}>+</p>
      {starsValue}
      <p onClick={Sub}>-</p>
    </>);
  }
```

Output::
First add :: displays 1 image that is animated until the end
Consecutive adds :: displays x images that display the final frame in the animation

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now, you can fetch image only once. This solution has some limitations with cors and max gif size.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this one.

```js
function App() {
  const [stars, setStars] = useState(0);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p onClick={() => setStars((s) => s + 1)}>+</p>
      {new Array(stars).fill().map((s, ind) => {
        return <Star key={ind}></Star>;
      })}
      <p onClick={() => setStars((s) => (s === 0 ? 0 : s - 1))}>-</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export function Star(props) {
  const [id] = useState(Math.random()); // Generate unique id for this item
  return (
    <img
      className="icon"
      src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/once-star-filled.gif?id=${id}`}
      alt="animated star"
    />
  );
}
```

I fix some notation errors, like function name should be started from small letter.
Moreover, you could use only one state to store and render stars gif.
Also, it is better to create another React function element `<Star />`. In this way you can reuse this gif later, and add some props, for instance different `alter text`, `src attribute` and et al.

[Update 1]

I disagree with @Karl comment, there is a significant flaw in his solution: when the `src` is formed using the `ind`, elements will be animated only once (ex: remove element with `ind=2` and add again element with `ind=2` give us a static image).

So I decided to supplement my answer with one more option, which I would not use in production, but it is interesting and solves the OP's problem.

What is the new solution? We fetch the image through `fetch`, convert it to `dataUrl`, delete the first part represented `metadata`, and pass it to the Star elements for rendering as `src` props.
Each element adds meta-information with its own Id, which does not affect the file itself, but the browser perceives the picture as new. Therefore, all start animates every time their appear on page.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [stars, setStars] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const ref = useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("./ezgif-2-110436c6c12b.gif")
      .then((res) => res.blob())
      .then(async (text) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (ev) => {
          setData(
            ev.currentTarget.result.replace("data:image/gif;base64", "")
          );
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(text);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p onClick={() => setStars((s) => s + 1)}>+</p>
      {data &&
        new Array(stars).fill().map((s, ind) => {
          return <Star src={data} key={ind}></Star>;
        })}
      <p onClick={() => setStars((s) => (s === 0 ? 0 : s - 1))}>-</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

/**
 *
 * @param {{src: string}} props
 * @returns
 */
export function Star(props) {
  const [id] = useState(Math.random());

  return (
    <img
      className="icon"
      src={`data:image/gif;base64;${id}` + props.src}
      alt="animated star"
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, unfortunately, nothing changed when I tried this. This is not a valid answer.

Comment: @Karl i have updated answer, please, add id in url query.

Comment: The solution does seem to be adding an id as I found in this similar question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831319/restart-a-gif-animation-without-reloading-the-file"

It is worth noting in this small comment that you should never arbitrarily assign id's with random numbers as since they are random, it is possible to have multiples which could create a catastrophic issue.

Unfortunately, both you and the answerer from this other forum post have created a possible issue. I will answer my question properly and address your issues there in more detail.